# how to get multiple fields from expo SecureStore

Tags: react-native, promise, expo

I am new to ES6 and react-native, trying to get multiple values from the SecureStore.

I think I am misunderstanding promises here ... global.userData is empty in the Promise.all(promises).then function. The relevant values do exist in the secure store

My code is:-

```
   getUserData(fields) {
        var promises = [];
        var that = this;
        global.userData = {};
        function getField(field) {
          return SecureStore.getItemAsync(field)
            .then(res => {
              console.log(field+"="+res); // this appears after the log below
              global.userData[field] = res;
             })
            .catch(error => {
              global.userData[field] = null;
            });
        }
        fields.map(field => {
          promises.push[getField(field)];
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(v) {
          console.log(global.userData); // this is empty
          that.setState({ isReady: true }); // allow page to render
        });
      }

    getUserData(["userId", "userName","etc"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad ... inadvertantly used

```
promises.push[getField(field)];
```

should have been:

```
promises.push(getField(field));
```

Suprised it wasn't detected as a syntax error ...